# WildFly add-user.bat The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: java, server, wildfly

When I try to run add-user.bat, cmd output that it cannot find the path specified and I really don't know what the problem is so if any of you can help me out that would be great.

I already tried to hard code path to my java instead of using JAVA_HOME variable, like it says on this site: [Solution I found but didn't work](http://@echo%20off%20rem%20-------------------------------------------------------------------------%20rem%20Add%20User%20script%20for%20Windows%20rem%20-------------------------------------------------------------------------%20rem%20rem%20A%20simple%20utility%20for%20adding%20new%20users%20to%20the%20properties%20file%20used%20rem%20for%20domain%20management%20authentication%20out%20of%20the%20box.%20%20rem%20$Id$%20%20@if%20not)

I use WildFly 16.

Script stops here: (at call "!DIRNAME!common.bat" :setDefaultModularJvmOptions "!JAVA_OPTS!")

```
@echo off
rem -------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem Add User script for Windows
rem -------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem
rem A simple utility for adding new users to the properties file used
rem for domain management authentication out of the box.

rem $Id$

@if not "%ECHO%" == ""  echo %ECHO%
@if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" setlocal

if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" (
  set "DIRNAME=%~dp0%"
) else (
  set DIRNAME=.\
)

pushd "%DIRNAME%.."
set "RESOLVED_JBOSS_HOME=%CD%"
popd

if "x%JBOSS_HOME%" == "x" (
  set "JBOSS_HOME=%RESOLVED_JBOSS_HOME%"
)

pushd "%JBOSS_HOME%"
set "SANITIZED_JBOSS_HOME=%CD%"
popd

if /i "%RESOLVED_JBOSS_HOME%" NEQ "%SANITIZED_JBOSS_HOME%" (
   echo.
   echo   WARNING: The JBOSS_HOME ^("%SANITIZED_JBOSS_HOME%"^) that this script uses points to a different installation than the one that this script resides in ^("%RESOLVED_JBOSS_HOME%"^). Unpredictable results may occur.
   echo.
   echo       JBOSS_HOME: "%JBOSS_HOME%"
   echo.
)

rem Setup JBoss specific properties
if "x%JAVA_HOME%" == "x" (
  set  JAVA=java
  echo JAVA_HOME is not set. Unexpected results may occur.
  echo Set JAVA_HOME to the directory of your local JDK to avoid this message.
) else (
  set "JAVA=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java"
)

rem set default modular jvm parameters
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
call "!DIRNAME!common.bat" :setDefaultModularJvmOptions "!JAVA_OPTS!"
```

Comment: What version of WildFly are you using? That script looks like it's from a newer version than WildFly 10.

Comment: Oh yes my bad I put in the wrong version. Its version is the newest so 16.

Comment: If you're not using Java 9+ you could comment that line out. I'd be interested to know what `DIRNAME` is set to. Maybe if you're starting from `%JBOSS_HOME%` then it's set to `.\` instead of `%JBOSS_HOME%\bin`.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I commented out call "!DIRNAME!common.bat" :setDefaultModularJvmOptions "!JAVA_OPTS! and add-user.bat still outputs System cannot find the path specified. I also started the script from %JBOSS_HOME%\bin which is C:\wildfly\bin if i am correct.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? Have you by chance tried the `add-user.ps1`? It's working for me on Windows 10 in the bin directory.

Comment: Thank you very much, using add-user.ps1 seems to work for me and i got it right.